# How to control UIPageViewController using Segmented Control?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a container view inside my main VC that contains a PageViewController with 3 VCs.

I wish that when the user taps on the segmented control it scrolls to the correct VC or when the user scrolls the UIPageVC it reflects on the segmented control. The problem is that the UIPageVC is inside the container view and I don't have access to the segmented control contained inside the main VC.

How can I do this? I am using storyboard with Swift 5 and iOS 12.

[A screenshot of the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV6j7.png)

Comment: You need to add delegate method in each of the 2 controllers. When the controller detect a change in page/tab it call the delegate method to say to the other controller « switched to page », and the controller implementation will do «if selected page/tab is not the asked page then go to page/tab»

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.